# Adding an affiliation that doesn't imply a conflict of interest

Tags: conference, acknowledgement, affiliation

It is okay to add an affiliation in the paper heading that I did not put in the domain conflicts (DC) at the time of submission? It was only after the submission of the paper that I got hired to a company, hence I submitted the paper without putting the company email domain in the DC during the submission.

I've done my rebuttal (i.e., writting the response letters to the reviewers) partly using the company resources, and the paper got accpeted. Thus the company now wants me to acknowledge and add the company name in the paper title only if allowed. In this situation, is it okay to add the company name in the paper heading?

Note*: What is DC?
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What do you mean by "domain of conflict"? What do you mean by adding a company name to the "title"? Do you mean "heading"? Your "rebuttal" to what?

Comment: And do you mean "conlict" in the title. I have no idea whether that is something real and can't find a definition.

Comment: @Buffy Sorry for confusion. I've revised the question to clarify my points based on your comments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would your affiliation pose a conflict of interest? You seem to have aligned interest, actually.

Comment: @Buffy -- journals generally won't send manuscripts out for review to people with the same affiliation.  Also, businesses might certainly have a financial conflict of interest.  What if a Pfizer scientist is trying to publish something from an FDA trial, for example.?

Comment: @Buffy I think OP's situation is that they did some work, perhaps as an academic, and after submission of the paper, they got a job in industry. They've now done some work on the paper on that company's time during the revision process. Ordinarily, one would have had to disclose potential conflicts of interest like employment on the initial submission (remember: COI does not mean ), but this is not a conflict OP disclosed because, well, it didn't exist at the time. Now the current employer wants them to list the company as an affiliation.

Comment: @BryanKrauseisonstrike Thank you for clarifying my situation!

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that the paper went to industry for review (at least for most fields I know), so it's unlikely your change of affiliation will impact the review process.

Of course, you don't want anything to pop up later.  You can certainly mention your change of affiliation in your response letter (assuming you're not in a double-blind process) -- or just drop a note to the section editor sitting on top of your review.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Scott! To clarify, I'd like to mention few more things. The review was double-blind. The rebuttal was finished, and the paper got accepted. Now, I am at the stage of preparing the final draft of the paper.

I will drop a footnote that 'the work was partly done at xxx company' if I am going to write the company name at the paper first page heading.

Comment: But since the chance that the paper had gone to my company people is not zero (although it is practically zero since I am working at a startup company), I am a bit worried though. But my former adivor said no worries since the conference chairs usually do not care of this matter much.